# IPad deleted from Apple ID and now I can't reset it

Tags: ipad, error

I am trying to erase my daughter's IPad but I deleted it from my Apple account.  It still shows I am logged in to my Apple ID on the IPad but when I try to erase all content and settings I get "Verification Failed There was an error connecting to the Apple ID server."  How do I fix this?

Comment: Does the iPad's internet connection work OK other than that? (worth checking because of the massive outage today in the UK & elsewhere)

Comment: Internet is working.  I have tried to sign out of my Apple ID since it still shows I am logged in.  It has me input the password but then I get the verification error again.

Comment: You need to release the device from 'Find my iPhone' rather than sign out

Answer (score 1):

Do you get to the part of the setup where the device asks for the Apple ID used to setup the device and the password or says activation lock?  If so then the device is still likely connected to the Apple ID that was used to set up the device.  If you log into the Apple ID website and remove the device or remove it from the account on another device in settings, that does not remove activation lock.  You have to erase the device via iCloud.com or the Find My [Device] app to remove activation lock/Find My Device.  You can also try setting up while connected to a computer with iTunes on it to try and get past the verification error in case it happens to be a problem with your internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. Toggle off find my iPhone through settings.
2. Login to your iCloud account & erase the iPad from your account. 
   Then do your stuff.